# Zend Framework: conditional column update

Tags: php, database, zend-framework

I have the following situation:

let's say I have two columns in my database table:

`visits` and `date`, I would like to update the `date` column only when `visits = 1`. Is there a Zend_Db_Expression for this purpose or I need to query the table first and check the `visits` value and then decide to update the `date` column or not.

Comment: update `table_name` set `date`= 'ur_val' where visits = 1; ?

Comment: thank you vimalnath for the response but this will not work because the `visits` column increments on each visit and I want to update the `date` column only when the first visit occurs.

Comment: how will you identify that the user visits for first time?

Comment: if at the time of visit the `visit=0`, it means the user visited first time ...

Answer (score 0):

you could use CASE statements with MySQL. Should also work on other SQL engines.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/case-statement.html

I don't think Zend_Db_Expression supports cases though. You will have to write that part manually.

Take a look at this UPDATE example using CASE:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/933-Using-CASE-Statements-In-A-SQL-UPDATE-Query.htm

Lucian